# How can I solve firebase authentication problem in my api developed in express?

Tags: firebase, express

I am working on a react application with express as a backend but the api for firebase authentication is not working.

I have tried testing it with Postman, but there;s internal server response coming(errorcode 500).

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const newUser ={
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        handle: req.body.handle
    };

    //TODO: validate user

    firebase
        .auth()
       .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email,newUser.password)
        .then((data) => {
          return res
            .status(201)
            .json({ message: `User ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });            
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.code});
        });
});
```

I expect it to post my data to firebase users, but its showing me internal server error 500.

**Server Log:**

```
TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
    at app.post (/srv/index.js:78:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: can you provide the log stack from firebase? 500 is server error. So whatever issue that you are having is in the server side. It would be better to check in logs for any discrepancy.

Comment: @Himanshu Bansal. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs... its evident that the `firebase.auth` is having the issue...

try this..

```
$ npm install firebase --save
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Then initialize as so:

```
const firebaseapp = require('@firebase/app');
require('@firebase/auth');

const firebase = firebaseapp.firebase

firebase.initializeApp({…})
```

then your app might work like this:

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
const newUser ={
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle
};

//TODO: validate user

firebase
    .auth()
   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email,newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `User ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });            
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({error: err.code});
    });
});
```

you can read more about this [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752#issuecomment-389508849)